# Load external page, update the URL in browser and keep page if browser is refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am attempting to build a website demo with Bootstrap 3 (because of IE7/8 support). The fixed navigation has 4 Menus anchors which link to a landing page for subject. Each of the menus have drop-downs with [x] amount of Sub-menus.

The page has to be static and bring in content from external plain .htmls pages. I have done this using

```
$(function(){
    $("#submenu a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behavior
        var url = this.href;
        $(".container").load(url);
    });
});
```

### My Problem

- I cannot seem to get the URLs to stay the same when the page is refreshed using the `location.hash` method.
- When clicking on a submenu from the dropdown, it loads in the same homepage container.

#### My Pages

The way I have done it so far: the homepage has a navigation with menus that have dropdown submenus.
Homepage right now with navigation and menus
[image]

When you click on the Menu link, it goes to that page. This html has a same navigation again, but the `active` menu href does not have a dropdown but is shown as a new div with nav-pills, that when clicked runs the load() script mentioned above.

Menu landing page with submenu as new div

[image]. the other menu links still have the dropdown function work as they are not active.

## What I am trying to achieve

1. From the homepage, Load the external MENU.htmls or SUBMENU.html in the same div container while updating the url.
2. If I share the url with someone, the pages opens with that specific content
3. If the menu page is clicked and `active`, update the navigation to include its submenus as in the new div area while disabling the dropdown (but dropdown still works on `collapse` in responsive mode). That way I do not have to add a different header to each page. The other menu links still have the dropdown function working as they are not active.
4. Reloads same page with content when browser refreshes
5. Basically this is want i would like the outcome to be: [image]

Any feedback, suggestions, sample links, etc are appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

---

UPDATE: I was not able to get the code to work from my end, however I found a video on [Single Page Applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xN9QxPtK2LM) that provides an example of what I wanted to happen...

Comment: `$(function(){
    $("#kva-menutabs a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behavior
        var url = this.href;
  window.history.pushState("obj", "new title", url);
  $(".container").load(url);
    });
});`  I found about push state [link] (https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-first-look-at-the-html5-history-api--net-28053) that updates the URL but if i were to refresh it shows the actual page (which has no formatting) instead of reloading it into the div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this

```js
$(function() {
  $("#submenu a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //To prevent the default anchor tag behavior
    $("#submenu a").removeClass("active")
    var url = this.href;
    var hash = new URL(url).hash;
    // localStorage.setItem("hash",hash)
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".container").load(url);
    location.hash = hash;
  });
  var hash = new URL(location.href).hash; // localStorage.get("hash");
  if (hash) { // if url / localStorage had a hash
    $("a[href='#" + hash + "']").click();
  }  
});
```

```css
#submenu a { text-decoration:none}
#submenu a.active { text-decoration: underline}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="submenu">
  <a href="#page1">Page 1</a><br/>
  <a href="#page2">Page 2</a><br/>
  <a href="#page3">Page 3</a><br/>  
</div>  

<div id="container"><div>
```

Comment: the code ended up working the same way previously. but it does not update the url.